# Javascript Template not created correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am using HTML templates embedded in a `<script>` using [Javascript Templates](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates) to render them.

Using a sample provided, the template is transmitted to the browser appropriately;

[image]

However, when collected by its ID, it does not look anything close to what it should;

[image]

What could be causing this; encoding or escaping? Something else entirely?

### **UPDATE**

As a quick workaround proposal, I tried moving my templates from an MVC partial, to webpack. Without going into too much detail, it seems as if using `html-loader` and manually bootstrapping the templates to a div worked a charm. Maybe MVC is screwing with something?

```
$('div.upload-templates').append(require('html-loader!./legacy/upload-templates.html'))
```

Still curious as to what really is going on...

Comment: `var template = document.getElementById('template-upload');
var expectedString = tmpl( template.value, data )`
expectedString will be something similar to what you might be expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/x-tmpl" id="tmpl-demo">
  <h3>{%=o.title%}</h3>
</script>
```

use this format. 
for example "https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates"